# how to use case with condition in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

using mysql query how to use `case` with condition like (`manager_id=2`).

i have three table with column

```
user
 - id
 - name
 - dept
 - manager_id
itemone
 - id
 - detail
 - status
 - amount
 - created_by
itemtwo
 - id
 - detail
 - status
 - amount
 - created_by
```

based on `status` column able to find **draft, pending, approved and rejected**.

> when my `manager_id` is `2` then calculate total for `pending` if not
>   show as 0.00; How to write query for this?

**Sample Select Query:**

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.dept, t1.manager_id, t2.draft_total, t2.pending_total, t2.approved_total, t2.rejected_total FROM user t1, 
(
    SELECT uat.created_by, SUM(uat.amount) AS total, SUM(uat.draft) AS draft_total, SUM(uat.pending) AS pending_total, SUM(uat.approved) AS approved_total, SUM(uat.rejected) AS rejected_total FROM 
    (
        SELECT id, detail, status, amount, CASE status WHEN 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END AS draft, CASE status WHEN 2 THEN amount ELSE 0 END AS pending, CASE status WHEN 3 THEN amount ELSE 0 END AS approved, CASE status WHEN 4 THEN amount ELSE 0 END AS rejected,created_by FROM itemone UNION ALL SELECT id, detail, status, amount, CASE status WHEN 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END AS draft, CASE status WHEN 2 THEN amount ELSE 0 END AS pending, CASE status WHEN 3 THEN amount ELSE 0 END AS approved, CASE status WHEN 4 THEN amount ELSE 0 END AS rejected,created_by FROM itemtwo
    ) 
    uat GROUP BY uat.created_by
) t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.created_by ORDER BY name ASC;
```

Find Table Schema in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69abba)

**Getting Following Result**

```
 name       | dept  | manager_id    | draft_total   | pending_total | approved_total    | rejected_total
user four   | Y     | 2             | 79.75         | 54.10         | 90.30             | 100.20  
user one    | X     | 1             | 79.75         | 54.10         | 90.30             | 100.20
user two    | X     | 1             | 84.25         | 0.00          | 0.00              | 0.00
```

**Expecting Output: If Manager id is 2 then Result Should be**

```
name        | dept  | manager_id    | draft_total   | pending_total | approved_total    | rejected_total
user four   | Y     | 2             | 79.75         | 54.10         | 90.30             | 100.20  
user one    | X     | 1             | 79.75         | 0.00          | 90.30             | 100.20
user two    | X     | 1             | 84.25         | 0.00          | 0.00              | 0.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this:

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.dept, t1.manager_id,
sum(case when t2.status=1 then t2.amount else 0 end) AS draft_total, 
sum(case when t2.status=2 and t1.manager_id=2  then t2.amount else 0 end) AS pending_total, 
sum(case when t2.status=2 then t2.amount else 0 end) AS approved_total, 
sum(case when t2.status=4 then t2.amount else 0 end) AS rejected_total
FROM user t1
inner join (
  select * from itemone
  union all 
  select * from itemtwo
) t2 on t1.id=t2.created_by 
group by t1.id
ORDER BY t1.name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

SELECT CASE user.manager_id WHEN 2 THEN SUM(pending) ELSE 0 END AS pending_total
FROM ...
WHERE ...

Comment: i need some thing like `user.manager_id WHEN 2 AND status WHEN 2 THEN SUM(pending)`